# Android Gradle Build failing with error "Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':module:debugFeatureCompileClasspath'"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-module

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':vision:processDebugFeatureManifest'.
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':vision:debugFeatureCompileClasspath'.
Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
 Required by:
     project :vision
  > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.core:core' that satisfies the version constraints: 
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0' --> 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Constraint path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugFeatureRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
       Constraint path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugFeatureRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
       Constraint path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugFeatureRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0

 Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.1.
 Required by:
     project :vision > project :coremodule > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2
  > Cannot find a version of 'androidx.core:core' that satisfies the version constraints: 
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0' --> 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Constraint path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugFeatureRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
       Constraint path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugFeatureRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
       Constraint path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugFeatureRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0

 Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
 Required by:
     project :vision > project :coremodule > com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0
     project :vision > project :coremodule > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2 > androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1
     project :vision > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
     project :vision > project :coremodule > com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0 > androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0
     project :vision > project :coremodule > com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0 > androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
     project :vision > project :coremodule > com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0 > androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0
     project :vision > androidx.media:media:1.0.0
    Cannot find a version of 'androidx.core:core' that satisfies the version constraints: 
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0' --> 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'SmHuRedesign:coremodule:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Dependency path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.1.0' --> 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0' --> 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0'
       Constraint path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugFeatureRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
       Constraint path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugFeatureRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
       Constraint path 'SmHuRedesign:vision:unspecified' --> 'androidx.core:core' strictly '1.0.0' because of the following reason: debugFeatureRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.0.0
```

This is an error which didn't occur until I started modularizing my app. I have the main support libraries included in the "core" or "base" module and then I have some specific modules such as this one, "vision", which give me errors. This continuous conflict between some (the same?) libraries doesn't let me build the app successfully. I can't find a way to make the libraries accept the `androidx`support library version I want to compile.

Comment: it says you're missing `androidx.core:core` ? show your gradle/dependencies?

Comment: @TWL will update ASAP, but I just want to make clear that these libraries worked perfectly when they were in the same module

Comment: then it might have to do with using `api` vs `implementation`

Comment: @TWL all libraries in the core module that are required are being declared with `api`